# High Resolution graphics laptop misconfiguration (1920x1200 15,6 ")

Tags: graphics, resolution, scaling

After searching all similar topics, I found no answers concerning a configuration issue on Kubuntu 12.04 on a nw6440 Compaq laptop with 1920x1200 display.

As the standard size of police was displaying very tiny characters, I tried several approaches to get a *readable display*, using configuration center to change the police size, but as there is almost nothing explaining which line does what, the results were not that good, especially using Firefox, and the new device notification that shows strangely overlapped characters in a too small display box, so that clicking on the right place to get an action done (open with dolphin, read with ...) is very uncertain.

My questions are:

1. Why is it so difficult to get such a display correctly working? 1366x768 or 1280 x  1024 is not making any difficulties, it seems to be a very basic problem of scaling, bu  can't find a simple solution.
2. Does someone have an idea about where to find correct, precise and brief instructions in order to fix this very annoying problem?

Comment: Everything should fit--you may be running into a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth trying different resolutions your monitor is capable of. Simple press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> to reduce the resolution (increasing text size), cycling through each possibility your monitor and graphics hardware can do. Some resolutions may seem to appear more than once.

To go the other way enter <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>